Getting Prettier and ES Lint working on save with Nuxt 3
I've been having the hardest time getting linting setup in a Nuxt 3 boiler plate.
My requirements:

Prettier for formatting and stylistic rules
ES Lint for fixing problematic patterns and code
Vue Recommend style guide rules
Fix on save
We use VS Code, so assuming some plugins are required?

You can see my attempts here: https://github.com/funkhaus/fuxt
And a PR from Antfu that still doesn't work: https://github.com/funkhaus/fuxt/pull/121
The best I can do is seem to get it working only flashing the fixes on save, and going back to incorrect format. Video here.
I have two plugins in VS Code, but I'm not even sure if they are required... Very confusing what it takes to get all this working.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Would love some direction from any linting pros out there!
are:

As a whole, Prettier was always a hacky and not performant way to have working alongside ESlint. Most Vue related rules are already available and working well indeed. I recommend sticking to Stylistic + ESlint. I can share a working setup that I achieved once back on a laptop.

@kissu would love to see it thank you. Happy to drop Prettier if the same thing can be done with ES Lint?

I have an eslint.config.mjs file with the following
import antfu from '@antfu/eslint-config';

export default antfu({
  vue: true,
  // typescript: true,
  formatters: {
    css: true,
    html: true,
    json: true,
    markdown: 'prettier',
  },
  stylistic: {
    indent: 2,
    quotes: 'single',
    semi: true,
  },
}, {
  rules: {
    'no-undef': 0,
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
    'unused-imports/no-unused-vars': 1,
  },
});

This in my package.json
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "lint:fix": "eslint --fix",
}

Those are my devDependencies:

@antfu/eslint-config
@vue/eslint-config-typescript
eslint
eslint-plugin-format
eslint-plugin-vue

And here are some part of my settings.json
"javascript.validate.enable": true,
"eslint.debug": true,
"eslint.useFlatConfig": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": "never",
  "source.fixAll": "always",
  "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit",
  "source.fixAll.stylelint": "always"
},
"eslint.validate": [
  "javascript",
  "javascriptreact",
  "typescript",
  "typescriptreact",
  "vue",
  "html",
  "markdown",
  "json",
  "jsonc",
  "yaml",
  "toml"
],

And I also have the ESlint extension in my VScode but NO Prettier.
The flashing occurs when you have ESlint fixing it, then Prettier coming over it aka a conflict between those 2 tools. By not having Prettier running, you have pretty much everything done in ESlint (with Stylistic).
Also, feel free to open your Output tab in VScode to check for some potential verbose problems.

This is an old answer that I gave for Nuxt2, restarting the ESlint server is still very relevant tho haha.

Update regarding the comments

vue is properly supported by antfu's setup, feel free to overwrite it with your own desired configurations
you can inspect the settings of Stylistic or inspect the rules already set
here are all his projects, plenty of various utilities to dig in if you're heavily interested into the ESlint config part
for the block order, you have this rule, otherwise I know that one of the Vue extensions can handle this part for you, maybe it's Nuxtr's nuxtr.vueFiles.firstTag or maybe Volar can do that, not sure but plenty of solutions to enforce consistency here as you can see.


Thanks for this. Close, but doesn't seem to implement the Vue recommend style guide rules?
Also, any ideas on how to get it to not put Vue script blocks first?

@DrewBaker updated my answer regarding your last comments.
